django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: API_gendarme.gendarmerie_name_id
school give us work and i have dit this.
i want to create an super user to test my API and then i get this error message
PS C:\Users\marcw\OneDrive\Documents\django school project\GNAPI> python .\manage.py createsuperuser
Username: marc
Email: marc@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: API_gendarme.gendarmerie_name_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marcw\OneDrive\Documents\django school project\GNAPI\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\marcw\OneDrive\Documents\django school project\GNAPI\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 89, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 238, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 172, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 155, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 78, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\marcw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: API_gendarme.gendarmerie_name_id

I tried to create a great user to be able to test my API but its sent me the errors you see there I tried to look it up but hela I was able to find it
this is my code here...

# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser




class Gendarmerie(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    commandant = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    departement = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    arrondissement = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modify_by = models.OneToOneField("API.Gendarme", on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)

    def __init__(self):
        return self.nom + " - " + self.commandant + ',' + self.departement + ', ' + self.arrondissement + ',' + self.region


class Gendarme(AbstractUser):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    matricule = models.CharField(max_length = 8, unique = True)
    numero_cni = models.CharField(max_length = 13, blank= True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length= 255,unique = True)
    mot_de_passe = models.CharField(max_length = 13)
    profile_picture = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 180)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    gendarmerie_name = models.OneToOneField(Gendarmerie, on_delete = models.CASCADE, auto_created=True)  
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    modify_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom + ',' +self.prenom+ ',' + self.matricule+ ',' + self.numero_cni+ ',' + self.phone_number+ ',' + self.email+ ',' + self.profile_picture+ ',' + self.residence+ ',' + self.grade


class Criminel(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField
    prenom = models.CharField
    nationaliter = models.CharField
    numero_cni = models.CharField
    photos = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    motifs = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_naissance = models.DateField()
    photo_preuve = models.CharField(max_length= 255)  # ajouter une preuve de crime (par exemple un document ou une image)
    nom_parent = models.CharField(max_length = 188)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrondissement = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    departement = models.CharField(max_length = 180)
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 96)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey("API.Gendarme", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __init__(self):
        return self.nom+","+self.prenom+","+self.nationaliter+","+self.numero_cni+","+self.photos+","+self.motifs+","+self.date_naissance+","+self.photo_preuve+","+self.nom_parent+","+self.residence+","+self.arrondissement+","+self.departement+","+self.region


# form.py



from .models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class listCriminel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "nom", "prenom", "nationaliter", "numero_cni", "photos", "motifs", "date_naissance",
         "photo_preuve", "nom_parent", "residence", "arrondissement", "departement", "region"
    )


class listGendarme(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
            "nom", "prenom", "matricule", "numero_cni", "phone_number", "email", "mot_de_passe", "profile_picture", "residence", "grade"
    )

class listGendarmerie(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
            "nom", "commandant", "departement", "arrondissement", "region"
    )




# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .form import *
from .models import *



admin.site.register(Criminel, listCriminel)
admin.site.register(Gendarme, listGendarme)
admin.site.register(Gendarmerie, listGendarmerie)




# views.py


from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import permissions
from .models import *
from .serializers import *


class CriminalApiView(APIView):
    
    permissions_class = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            criminel = Criminel.objects.all()
            serializers = CriminelSerializers(criminel, many=True)
            return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = {
                'nom': request.data.get['nom'],
                'prenom': request.data.get['prenom'],
                'nationaliter': request.data.get['nationaliter'],
                'numero_cni':request.data.get['numero_cni'],
                'photos':request.data.get['photos'],
                'motifs': request.data.get['motifs'],
                'date_naissance': request.data.get['date_naissance'],
                'photo_preuve': request.data.get['photo_preuve'],
                'nom_parent': request.data.get['nom_parent'],
                'residence': request.data.get['residence'],
                'arrondissement': request.data.get['arrondissement'],
                'departement': request.data.get['departement'],
                'region': request.data.get['region'],
            }

            serializer = CriminelSerializers(data=data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return  Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    


class GendarmeApiViews(APIView):
    permission_classe = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            gendarme = Gendarme.objects.all()
            serializers = GendarmeSerializers(gendarme, many= True)
            return Response(serializers.data, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = {
                'nom': request.data.get['nom'],
                'prenom': request.data.get['prenom'],
                'nationaliter': request.data.get['nationaliter'],
                'numero_cni': request.data.get['numero_cni'],
                'photos': request.data.get['photos'],
                'motifs': request.data.get['motifs'],
                'date_naissance': request.data.get['date_naissance'],
                'photo_preuve': request.data.get['photo_preuve'],
                'nom_parent': request.data.get['nom_parent'],
                'residence': request.data.get['residence'],
                'arrondissement': request.data.get['arrondissement'],
                'departement': request.data.get['departement'],
                'region': request.data.get['region']
            }

            serializers = GendarmeSerializers(data=data)
            
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class GendarmerieApiView(APIView):
    permission_classe = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            gendarme = Gendarmerie.objects.all()
            serializer = GendarmerieSerializers(gendarme, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = {
                'nom': request.data.get['nom'],
                'commandant': request.data.get['commandant'],
                'departement': request.data.get['departement'],
                'arrondissement': request.data.get['arrondissement'],
                'region': request.data.get['region']
            }
            serializers = GendarmerieSerializers(data=data)
            
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                
            else:
                return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)




# urls.py 

from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
  path("criminel/", CriminalApiView.as_view()),
  path("gendarme/", GendarmeApiViews.as_view()),
  path("gendarmerie/", GendarmerieApiView.as_view()),
]




Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
